# Connecting cleansing components to tFileList - Talend

Tags: talend

What is the best way to apply logic to objects during an iteration of tFileList.

The issue is that if I use a tFileList to get a list of files, i am not able to use tJavaRow or jMap to create the filename that i want the file to be renamed. Basically, if i have zip files with years(2010,2011,2012 etc) and each zip file contains files with the same name (f1.csv, f2.csv, f3.csv), i want to iterate through the compressed files, uncompress them and rename the files with 
f1_2010.csv, f2_2010.csv, f3_2010.csv..f1_2012.csv etc.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you edit your question to include screenshots of any jobs you've created to attempt this so far?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate links are providing a way to execute components based on events or facts while main links are transfering data between components.

With something looking like that you should be able to resolve your problem :

```
tFileList_1 --iterate--> tFileUnarchive_1
                           |
                        onComponentOK
                           |
                         tFileList_2 -- iterate --> tFileCopy_1
                           |
                        onComponentOK
                           |
                         tFileArchive_1
```

Use `((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))` in your tFileUnarchive to get the ZIP path.
In tFileCopy use `((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_2_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))` to get the path of file and config it to be a rename.

For your name modification you can add tJava on "onComponentOK" links. By using `globalMap.put("year",((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH")).substring(x,x))` or more complicated code. And use these variables in your others components parameters.